# What's res.render( ) for in mongoDB?

Tags: express

What does `res.render` do over here. Why not use res.send instead?

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('hello_mongo_express').findOne({}, function(err, doc){
        res.render("request handled");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Express thing, not MongoDB.

[`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) renders the HTML view template named `"request handled"` and returns it as the response whereas [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) will simply send the `"request handled"` string as a response.

Typically, you'd also pass some data into `res.render` that the template references to populate the template. As in:

```
res.render("request handled", {title: doc.title});
```

Comment: Does render in this context mean it will fill out the markup template with "values"?

Comment: @nosille Right, generate the HTML from the markup template with the values passed in.